# magit: display the commit log around the commit I'm interested in

Tags: magit

How can I jump to the commit log around the commit I'm interested in?

I use `magit-blame` a lot while reading the history of a project.  While doing that, I `RET` to see the commit that changed the line I'm interested in.  Now, from that `*magit-revision` buffer, I can open a history buffer  using `magit-log` with the specified revision on top, but how can I see the log *around* the commit?

Yes I can use `magit-log` with `$rev^10...master` to see the history from `$rev` to `master` but a) this will take long time if the `$rev` is old, b) not clean ;p.

Is there better way to list commit log with 10 parents and 10 children?

I assume what I want to do is to get commits like this:

```
git rev-list 71058854a42cd1~10.. | tail -n 20
```

and plot them in the buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I plan to implement that. See [Given a commit, show log of "surrounding" commits #2990](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2990).